# S3 Sync issue running in azure devops pipeline on linux

Tags: amazon-s3, azure-devops, aws-cli

I've also asked directly in the GitHub of the project, but I'm also taking a chance since more people look on here.

Confirm by changing [ ] to [x] below:

- [x] I've gone though the [User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html) and the [API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/)
- [x] I've searched for [previous similar issues](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues) and didn't find any solution

Issue is about usage on:

- [x] Service API : I want to do X using Y service, what should I do?
- [ ] CLI : passing arguments or cli configurations.
- [ ] Other/Not sure.

**Platform/OS/Hardware/Device**
What are you running the cli on?
I'm running the CLI on ubuntu-latest (currently ubuntu-18.04), I've also tried with ubuntu-20.04.
This is used in my CD on azure devops

**Describe the question**
I keep running the following command command as part of my CD pipeline and it keeps failing with 255 error code. When I run the same command locally on my machine with the same user profile, it works. My local machine is a macOS 10.15 though.

```
aws s3 sync /mybuildartifact/ s3://bucketName/subDir/ --delete --profile myUserProfile --debug
```

I've made sure to check that the CLI properly installed the user profile and that the command has access to it. I've used the following commands to setup the user profile and check it's existence (I'm using the same method to test locally)

```
aws configure import --csv file://$(serviceUserCredentials.secureFilePath)
aws configure list-profiles
```

**Logs/output**
Get full traceback and error logs by adding `--debug` to the command.

> 2020-11-24 16:24:11,346 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.sync.metadata: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1a9618a320>
> 2020-11-24 16:24:11,346 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.sync.copy-props: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1a9618a320>
> 2020-11-24 16:24:11,346 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.custom.sync: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at 0x7f1a968225f8>
> 2020-11-24 16:24:11,346 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.sync.metadata-directive: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1a9618a320>
> 2020-11-24 16:24:11,346 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.sync.size-only: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1a9618a320>
> 2020-11-24 16:24:11,346 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.custom.sync: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at 0x7f1a968225f8>
> 2020-11-24 16:24:11,346 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.sync.exact-timestamps: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1a9618a320>
> 2020-11-24 16:24:11,346 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.custom.sync: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at 0x7f1a968225f8>
> 2020-11-24 16:24:11,346 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.sync.delete: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1a9618a320>
> 2020-11-24 16:24:11,346 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.custom.sync: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at 0x7f1a968225f8>
> 2020-11-24 16:24:11,346 - MainThread - botocore.utils - DEBUG - IMDS ENDPOINT: http://169.254.169.254/
> 2020-11-24 16:24:11,349 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - Starting new HTTP connection (1): 169.254.169.254:80
> 2020-11-24 16:24:11,351 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - http://169.254.169.254:80 "PUT /latest/api/token HTTP/1.1" 400 11
> 2020-11-24 16:24:11,351 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exception caught in main()
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "awscli/clidriver.py", line 453, in main
> File "awscli/customizations/commands.py", line 198, in **call**
> File "awscli/customizations/commands.py", line 191, in **call**
> File "awscli/customizations/s3/subcommands.py", line 709, in _run_main
> File "awscli/customizations/s3/subcommands.py", line 480, in _run_main
> File "awscli/customizations/s3/subcommands.py", line 473, in get_client
> File "botocore/session.py", line 778, in create_client
> File "botocore/session.py", line 827, in _resolve_region_name
> File "botocore/session.py", line 237, in get_config_variable
> File "botocore/configprovider.py", line 289, in get_config_variable
> File "botocore/configprovider.py", line 386, in provide
> File "awscli/utils.py", line 60, in provide
> File "awscli/utils.py", line 65, in _get_instance_metadata_region
> File "awscli/utils.py", line 105, in retrieve_region
> File "awscli/utils.py", line 114, in _get_region
> File "botocore/utils.py", line 298, in _fetch_metadata_token
> botocore.utils.BadIMDSRequestError: <botocore.awsrequest.AWSRequest object at 0x7f1a96155160>

Comment: `I keep running the following command command as part of my CD pipeline and it keeps failing with 255 error code. When I run the same command locally on my machine with the same user profile, it works.` Azure DevOps use project collection service account to run command in pipeline. Please make sure it has sufficient permission, as same as your locally account.

Comment: like I stated, I was using the exact same user profile. I answered my question with the answer I got from contributors to the repository on GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

So I got a response on the GitHub that linked me to another issue about some reason related to how the networking is done. for more details you can see the following issue:

https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/5623

> In some cases, like when running the AWS CLI on an Azure instance, another service can be running at the same non-routable IP address used by IMDS. One way to get around this is to explicitly set a region.

As soon as I set a region to the profile I was using to run the command, it worked.

This also explains why I wasn't having issues running locally.

Comment: Thanks for the sharing. You could mark it, in case someone else faces this same error message.